# How do I find a package that provides a given file in OpenSuSE?

Tags: opensuse, rpm, zypper

I am thinking on some like `Contents-<arch>.gz` on Debian. A network service were also okay. Does it exist?

*Simple elaboration:* For example, we need a binary named `exampletool`, which we know very good from other distributions or operation systems. We want to install that, for example, with zypper. But zypper can only install a package. To find out, in which package can we find the required `exampletool` binary, we need to do practically a search, and ideally a fast, indexed search in the *file list of the currently not installed, but in the repositories available packages*. On debian, there is an index file in the package repositories named `Contents-amd64.gz`, in which we can find the required package with a single `zgrep` command. I am looking for some similar, single-command solution for OpenSUSE, too. If there is none, a web service were also okay for the same functionality.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To search from all available packages to find a particular file, you can use the option `wp` or `se --provides --match-exact` as an example:

```
zypper se --provides --match-exact hg
```

You will see output similiar to the following:

```
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...

S | Name      | Summary                  | Type   
--+-----------+--------------------------+--------
  | mercurial | Scalable Distributed SCM | package
```

From that point you can install the package through a standard zypper install

```
zypper in mercurial
```

It should be noted that `zypper wp` is obsolete and may no longer be available.

Comment: This is not always reliable. I don't know why but file names such as `zypper search --provides [--match-exact] getenforce` do not return results, while `zypper search --provides nslookup` does.

Comment: I believe that `provides` are symbolic and set manually by the packager, but I don't know much about how openSUSE creates packages. As such, they don't necessarily reflect package file contents.

Comment: I'm on openSUSE Leap 15 and searching for `ping` package, `zypper se --provides --match-exact ping` gives me nothing but `zypper se --provides --match-exact /usr/bin/ping` gives me `iputils`, to ensure getting result maybe `zypper se --provides --match-exact $(which command)`, for me `zypper se --provides --match-exact $(which ping)` then. Edit: I just saw the `scout bin command` below that I prefer since works with `scout bin ping` and above all is much faster.

Answer (score 11):

To the googlers of the future: next to @SailorCire 's wonderful solution :-), there is also a tool named `scout`, which is able to search in practically everything, we can find rpm-s for a binary just as we can find the jars for a given java class.

For example, we can use scout's `bin` command to find out what package provides the `hg` executable:

```
scout bin hg
```

The result of this search is the `mercurial` package:

```
 repository      | package   | path     | binary
-----------------+-----------+----------+--------
 zypp (repo-oss) | mercurial | /usr/bin | hg
```

Comment: Can you please be a little more specific about the `scout` tool ? Can you give its' complete name or URL to its' code ?

Comment: @SebMa It was downloadable from rpm, probably by zypper. It is possible, that it was in a non-standard repo. I can't remember very well :-( I don't use SuSE any more. But it is quite possible that I will be, then I will check it and explain what I found. It is possible, that SuSE has changed a lot since then.

Comment: On my Jolla1 device (SailFishOS), `zypper wp scout` says `No matching items found.`

Comment: @SebMa Googling for "scout tool rpm" I found [this](https://fedora.pkgs.org/30/fedora-x86_64/scout-0.4-23.fc30.noarch.rpm.html) link on the spot, in the current moment I can't help more. Probably you will need to install it from  some non-standard repository.

Comment: On the link you've provided, it says : "Scout is an interface to Tomboy notes or Gnote that uses DBus to
communicate."
 I'm not sure that's the tool we are looking for.

Comment: On the other hand, thanks to the second result of "scout tool rpm", I found this [scout](https://github.com/openSUSE/scout/). Is this the one ?

Answer (score 2):

Even later to the party than @Vicente Bolea, but I have found a solution by checking the documentation of `zypper se`, which was suggested by @SailorCire:

```
zypper search --file-list <filename>
```

or its short version

```
zypper se -f <filename>
```

searches in the file lists of the available packages

Answer (score 1):

I am late to this party, but to add my grain of salt.

Currently, there is not a reliable way to do this in `OpenSUSE`. In theory, the package maintainers must add all the files it "provides" in the `Provides` section in the spec package. But this is seldom used.

Alternatively, if you have an idea in which package the wanted file it is you could individually inspect the files inside the rpm as in this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57397745/2420872

Comment: I think the provides is a very different thing (not sure in OpenSUSE any more). The last what would be reliable if it depends on what the package maintainers manually say. The question asks for what actually lists the files in all packages in the remote repository, and searches in them. How about the other answers? zypper was quite a reliable solution for me (at the time - I do not use opensuse any more).

Answer (score 1):

My first shot would always be cnf aka command-not-found:

> cnf yelp
>
> The program 'yelp' can be found in following packages:
>
> - yelp [ path: /usr/bin/yelp, repository: zypp (openSUSE-Leap-15.4-1) ]
> - yelp [ path: /usr/bin/yelp, repository: zypp (repo-oss) ]
>
> Try installing with:
> sudo zypper install yelp

To further check on available versions and repos, use opi, the OBS Package Installer (CLI), to search and install almost all packages available for openSUSE and SLES:

> $ opi yelp
>
> 1. yelp
> 2. yelp-xsl
> 3. yelp-tools
> 4. libyelp0
> 5. yelp-lang
> 6. yelp-devel
>    Pick a number (0 to quit):

1

> You have selected package name: yelp
>
> 1. GNOME:STABLE:41 ?                         | 41.2                      | x86_64
>    Pick a number (0 to quit):

Picking 1 will first add the repo, if required, enable it, and download and install the package.

The advantages of opi become obvious when there are multiple versions to choose from:

$ opi php8

> You have selected package name: php8
>
> 1. devel:languages:php:php82 ?               | 8.2.4                     | x86_64
> 2. devel:languages:php ?                     | 8.1.17                    | x86_64
> 3. devel:languages:php:php81 ?               | 8.1.13                    | x86_64
> 4. devel:languages:php:php80 ?               | 8.0.28                    | x86_64
> 5. home:13ilya !                             | 8.2.4                     | x86_64
> 6. home:mmanu84:php8:php82 !                 | 8.2.4                     | x86_64
> 7. home:SCNOPS:php81 !                       | 8.1.17                    | x86_64
> 8. home:illuusio:php-next !                  | 8.1.17                    | x86_64
>    Pick a number (0 to quit):

Which will allow you to select between PHP 8.0.28, 8.1.13, 8.1.17, and 8.2.4. Note that there's no stable package yet, all are either labeled devel or home.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Gecko Linux XFCE. I opened Yast2 and installed **gnome-search-tool** and **gnome-shell-search-provider-nautilus**. It works fine, just like Catfish.