# Trouble using a Qt 6 application on an older (SLES 15) machine

Tags: xkb, qt, sles, plugin

I'm trying to run an app which apparently uses some Qt6 capabilities on my SLES 15 SP5. When I do that, I get the following error message:

```
qt.qpa.plugin: From 6.5.0, xcb-cursor0 or libxcb-cursor0 is needed to load the Qt xcb platform plugin.
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: wayland, offscreen, xcb, wayland-egl.

Application could not be initialized!
    This is likely due to missing Qt platform dependencies.
    For a list of dependencies, please refer to https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/linux-requirements.html
    To view missing libraries, set QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1 and re-run the application.

Warning: OpenGL Version check failed. Falling back to Mesa software rendering.
qt.qpa.plugin: From 6.5.0, xcb-cursor0 or libxcb-cursor0 is needed to load the Qt xcb platform plugin.
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: wayland, offscreen, xcb, wayland-egl.
```

Earlier versions of this app used to work. Also, I don't see a distribution package mentioning something like "libxcb-cursor".

I tried choosing other platform plugin settings; wayland and wayland-egl just failed, and offscreen succeeded, but showed nothing.

What can I do to get this application to run:

Notes:

- The app is NVIDIA NSight Compute 2024.1, in case that matters.
- Assume I can get root access (but let's not get too crazy)

Comment: there's no reason to assume the package would be called like that. the Qt QPA component just calls for "something" called libxcb-cursor0 – whether that is a library filename, a package name on a specific distro or just a "human name" for some software component is not emergent from the error message. Now, I don't have old SLES machines, can you search for a package containing a file named `*xcb-cursor0*`?

Comment: also, there's something seemingly broken with your OpenGL native libraries; that's going to be hard to debug, since I don't think there's an "official" way of installing a modern set of nvidia drivers on old SLES, so this is probably been done manually through nvidia's binary installer?

Comment: @MarcusMüller: 1. There's [this way](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/158041/how-do-i-find-a-package-that-provides-a-given-file-in-opensuse) to search for packages providing a file, I'll try it when I'm next near that system. 2. Previous versions of the app didn't seem to have a problem with the OpenGL drivers, and TBH I'm always afraid to mess around with those, because from painful experience doing so can go south quite easily.